# Jssor slider fill both parent height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I want my jssor slider to always keep the dimensions(both height and width) of parent node. With this code it only fill the width, but it scales the height which is the behavior I want to prevent mostly for responsive uses.

```
  var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
        {$Duration:500,$Delay:30,$Cols:8,$Rows:4,$Clip:15,$SlideOut:true,$Formation:$JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs,$Assembly:2049,$Easing:$Jease$.$OutQuad},
    ];

    var jssor_1_options = {
        $AutoPlay: 1,
        $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
        },
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
        },
        $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
        }
    };

    var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

    /*#region responsive code begin*/

    var MAX_WIDTH = 3000;

    function ScaleSlider() {
        var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
        var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;

        if (containerWidth) {

            var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);

            jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(expectedWidth);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
    }



    ScaleSlider();

    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    /*#endregion responsive code end*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the new API method `$ScaleSize`.

```
var MAX_WIDTH = 3000;
var MAX_HEIGHT = 3000;

function ScaleSlider() {
    var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
    var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;
    var containerHeight = containerElement.clientHeight;

    if (containerWidth) {
        var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);
        var expectedHeight = Math.min(MAX_HEIGHT || containerHeight, containerHeight);

        jssor_1_slider.$ScaleSize(expectedWidth, expectedHeight);
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
}
```